# Crash on TextView - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a crash while inflating a view from xml. Its a listView cell view.

Inflation code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_ads_list, parent, false);
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/cell_adsListView"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/top_border"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/hj_color_ads_list_separator"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some long title"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ad_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/hj_color_title"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:focusable="false"

        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView_ad_title"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"

                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ProgressBar

            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressSpinner"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout_cell_ads_list"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView_time"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/username_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView_time"
            android:focusable="false"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="right|center|top"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:text="author name very long"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@color/hj_color_blue"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:id="@+id/textView_authorName"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            // IconTextView
            <IconTextView
                android:text="{fa-user}"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/hj_icon_color"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView_authorName"
                android:focusable="false"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView_time">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:text="city name"
                android:textColor="@color/hj_color_blue"
                android:id="@+id/textView_cityName"
                android:gravity="right|top"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            // IconTextView
            <IconTextView
                android:text="{fa-map-marker}"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView_cityName"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/hj_icon_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Line #24 is the first TextView in the beginning.

The crash is happening only in android 4.0.3 which is the minimum version set for the app. All higher versions are running fine and do not have this crash. Could someone please help whats wrong in the code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have the logcat. The crash log is from Crashlytics.

Comment: Then run up an emulator for Android v4.0.3 and try to replicate the problem. As it stands, your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to help.

Comment: sorry, logcat is must.....

Comment: I created a virtual device with API 15 (Android 4.0.3). And it is not crashing. Crashlytics crashes are coming from Samsung (GT-I9100) devices with v4.0.3 only.

Comment: Sorry you won't want to hear this but Samsung devices cause more problems than any other manufacturers' devices. Samsung have done a lot of adaptations to their versions of Android which aren't considered to be within the guidelines. All I can suggest is do some further searching to see if you can find a common problem with that device and Android version.

Comment: This is so weird. I recently updated the compileSdkVersion to 22 from 19 and this started to happen. In 19, it was fine. I also had updated buildToolsVersion from 19.1.0 to 22.0.1. The minSdkVersion is 15, unchanged. TargetSDKVersion changed from 19 to 22. Could this have caused the problem? because i did not make changes to the XML file.